# PayPal IPN messages: pending_reason

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

Took a project using CodeIgniter and in the PayPal logs I see two transactions from several thousand saying:

```
"pending_reason":"paymentreview"
"pending_reason":"echeck" // Potentially this https://www.paypal.com/us/cshelp/article/why-was-my-payment-sent-as-an-echeck-and-why-is-it-pending-help285
```

May someone clarify what it means please? Do we have to do anything else or does the customer? To clarify, we are issuing a refund. Out of the several thousand, only these seem to be the problematic ones.

Any guidance on this would be most excellent.

I would like to stress that StackOverflow is a terrible website.

Answer (score 0):

Echeck payments are from a bank funding source without an instant backup funding source. They will be pending until they clear the bank.